# jQuery: How I can validate simultaneously checkbox and input text?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input, checkbox

I have a div and into this I have 2 checkboxes and 2 inputs text but I want validate or check if all inputs are empty to display an alert or error and that fill at least one input (checkbox or text) because I don't do two validations: 1 for checkboxes and 2 for inputs text... exists any way to do this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="t_disp">
    <p>
        <label for="7x24">7x24</label>
        <input id="7x24" name="7x24" type="checkbox"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="5x8">5x8</label>
        <input id="5x8" name="5x8" type="checkbox"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="especial">Especial</label>
        <input id="especial" name="especial" type="text"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ticket">Ticket</label>
        <input id="ticket" name="ticket" type="text"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get how many inputs are filled/checked:

```
var filled = $('#t_disp input').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).is('[type=checkbox]') ? this.checked : this.value;
}).length;

if ( filled ) {
   // at least one input is filled
} else {
   // all inputs are empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the text inputs you can check the value.

```
$('#especial').val();
$('#ticket').val();
```

For the check boxes you can check if they're checked.

```
$('#7x24').attr('checked'); // returns 'checked' if checked
$('#5x8').attr('checked');
```

Then you just need to stick them all in a condition. If they're all empty or not checked then you show your error.

P.S. In my experience `id=` beginning with numbers don't work all that well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function

```
function validate()
{

    var isFormValid = false;

        $("#t_disp input:text").each(function()
        {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0)
           {      isFormValid = true;    }
        });

     var len =  $("#t_disp input:checked").length;
     if( len > 0 ) { isFormValid = true; }

        if (!isFormValid) 
        alert("Please fill atleast on one field.");

}
```